# Html Layout Issue Panel Full Height

Tags: html, layout, css

I am looking help with an HTML Layout.  Here is the fiddle > http://jsfiddle.net/jSUNt/  Basicly what I am looking to do is have the 'Grey' Bar on the left become the full height of the window with the blue bar on the right staying a relative size.  e.g. as content gets bigger it gets bigger.

Can someone adjust my code to make this happen

Comment: Here is an working example of what you want : [**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jSUNt/22/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
#body{ width: 100%; }

#menu {
width: 30%;
background-color: lightGray;
height:100%;
float: left;
display:block;
position:fixed;    
}

#content {
width: 70%;
min-height: 50px;
background-color: lightBlue;
float:right;
display:block;
}
```